# Sending an Email to Members of a Team in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are trying to maximize the usage of Microsoft Teams and one of the things we want to do is use the channel's email adress to send emails to the members of that team/channel.

All good but how to do that?! If you get the channel's email address from the channel's context menu, the result is that the email you write gets posted in the team chat.
That is NOT what we want, because as I am sure you all know, channel threads dissapear after a while and it is notoriously hard to bring them up again/find them etc.

Therefore, emailing content is still a good choice for revisiting that content.

What are we missing?

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say there are different approaches :
Generally I would recommend for a Teams App to make use of the **Teams modalities** such as:

- [Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userscopeteamsappinstallation-get-chat?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [User Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/projectrome-notification?view=graph-rest-beta)

Note: If you send a message , and the user does not open the Teams client at all, then the Teams backend will automagically send an e-mail reminder to that user, without you needing to do a thing.

If you still need/want to send e-mails to each member of the Team/channel - you will need to :

- get the groupId for the team
- get the e-mail address for the [O365 Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#code-try-1) that for that Team
- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$select=displayName,mail
- send a e-mail to the group

or get [list of users in that Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples)

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams//members
  the response will include e-mail addresses and displaynames
- send an e-mail to each user or put all users in TO/CC/BCC

Comment: Thank you Jos. I will try your suggestions. The reason I want to do an email is because of the volatility of the teams chats - something I am struggling to understand or appreciate or find any good reason for it. There might be a valuable thread which you want to save for future reference - and you can send it via email to the members of that channel before it vanishes and can never remember how to find it again... :(

Comment: Jos - ok, I thought that maybe the O365 Group email you indicated above is something else from what I knew. But it isn't. Sending an email to that email address merely puts the email in the team chat - which is not what I want... Can there ANYTHING be done to enable that email addres and make it work like an email address is supposed to work?

Comment: have you tried changing the e-mail handling on the O365 Group ?
https://sympmarc.com/2019/08/25/sending-emails-to-an-office-365-group-when-the-group-was-created-from-teams/

Comment: That did it for the whole team - definitely a step forward! :-) Yay! With a minor hindrance - whoever sents it does not receive it back, it only shows in the "Sent" folder - even if that person is a member of the team that the communication is sent to :D 

However, it does not work for the channel's email address. I will continue digging but if you have any additional suggestions, I would appreciate it. I will mark the question resolved, since basically your indication is a solution for the problem title. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Each Team has an email address for its members--not the email address that sends email INTO the Teams environment and posts it in the channel, but an email address for the members. It is not readily viewable in Teams (I think there's a way, but I don't see it now) but you can usually guess it--it's the Team name mashed together without spaces (e.g. the "IT Management Folks" team is probably itmanagementfolks@yourdomain.com. It's easy to see in the Teams (or Groups) Admin Interface in Microsoft 365, so your admin can tell you if you can't guess. See, Teams are also Microsoft 365 groups, so they can be emailed like any group.

Comment: Thanks! Outlook didn't recognise this email address until I completed it. Only then it was recognised and even shown how many people are in the group.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for some way to use the email adress of the M365 group that supports a Team as a Distribution List. Realized I could do this in AAD, just change the setting on the "Group write back state" to "Distribution".

[group write back state on AAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRkGQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Having searched high and low for an answer to this, but today I have found the relevant settings to enable you to effectively treat an MS Teams team as a distribution list. If you go to the Exchange Admin centre -> Groups -> Microsoft 365.  From here, find the group name and then edit the settings. Then set the checkboxes as shown.  The key to this is "Send copied of group conversations ..." as this will expand the Team email to the email addresses of its members.

[image: Screenshot of Group screen]

Answer (score 0):

You can get a distro list via Sharepoint that will allow you to send an email to everyone in the channel.

In Teams, select open in sharepoint -> In Sharepoint, go to site settings -> Site Permissions -> Advanced Permissions Settings -> Select the Members Link -> Click on it again -> You should now see a 'work email' distro list that will include all members in the channel. You can copy that into outlook and send the communication.

This has worked for me but there is so many settings in Microsoft that you really never know.